# Sensitivity analysis of features in a Random Forest Model

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, lasso, importance, sensitivity-analysis

I have a built a large Random Forest Classifier and was able to output the feature importance as below:

[image: Feature Importance]

I understand that this importance is a based on mean decreased impurity. But how to interpret this - for those with high relative importances, is it roughly the same as small p-value in linear regression?

Moreover, I'm wondering how to further check on the features' impact on my response variable Y - something like a sensitivity analysis. I went with a Lasso regression and tried to find coefficients which are more interpretable. But the R-squared on my test set was terrible( ~ -10). Is there a way to show, for example, that the feature which tops on the importance plot loosely speaking impacts my Y variable positively or negatively?

Thanks!